# Global variables cleared in Workbook_Open Event

Tags: excel, vba, global-variables

I am trying to set some default global ranges that are set during the `Workbook_Open()` method.

I have drilled down to the following simple example that fails.

I have a global range variable and the `Workbook_Open()` sub in the "ThisWorkbook" module in the Microsoft Excel Objects folder (see picture for reference). It looks like the following:

```
 Public testCell As Range
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Public Sub Workbook_Open()
 Set testCell = Range("F1")
 End Sub
```

I then try to access this assigned variable in a sheet module sub:

```
 Public sub mySub()
 testCell.Value = "Hello World!"
 End Sub
```

On trying to execute the above I get a '424' Object Required error. Are there any obvious errors in approach or syntax?

For reference here's my file structure:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In VBA you would write `testCell.Value="Hello World!"`.

Comment: And declare `testcell` in a normal module. And best to specify a sheet too.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Scope.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to insert the following line into your code module `Module1`:

```
 Public testCell As Range
```

After that, your code should work. The reason for this is explained in the linke that @SJR provided. As he already mentioned, public declarations of variables can be placed in code modules, not workbook or worksheet objects.

Comment: Just to add to the above, it seems that the above works and indeed other SO answers suggest using a global variable module. The only hitch that I can see is that I have to reference it like this: `myLocalRange = Module1.testCell` but it's a small price to pay.

Comment: If you declare your Global variable as suggested, you dont need to reference with `Module1`. You can just use: `myLocalRange = testCell`. That's the point of a **Global** variable, you can reference it from anywhere within your project